# Transactional email event

Tags: event-observer, email, transactional

Some of my customers have second email address as customer attribute. I would like to send an copy of every transactional email to customer second email address. I wonder - if magento have event which firing during transactional email sending?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are unfortunately no events in the `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` and `Mage_Core_Model_Email` classes.

If you would like to extend the functionality to send to multiple customer e-mail addresses, the following could be a possible way for you:

1. Rewrite `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` and `Mage_Core_Model_Email`
2. Do only rewrite the `send()` function and put your own events in there.

For `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` it could look like this:

```
class Your_Module_Model_Core_Email_Template extends Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template {
/**
* wraps send() method of parent, supplies before and after events
*/
public function send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent('email_template_send_before', array('email' => $this, 'email_to' => $email));
    $return = parent::send($email, $name, $variables);
    Mage::dispatchEvent('email_template_send_after', array('email' => $this, 'email_to' => $email));
   return $return;
}
```

`$email` and `$name` can be an array (see the `send()` method in `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template`).

Do it analog for `Mage_Core_Model_Email`.

3. Use your newly created events to hook hin and add the customers second e-mail address.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712407/how-do-i-trigger-a-email-in-magento-when-an-order-is-made) question might help you. There is an event called `sales_order_place_after`. Or you can create a rewrite for   `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail` and add the CC there.